does it make a difference to initialize google tag manager with GAU property vs GA4 measurement ID?
We're finishing up the migration from GAU to GA4 for our various accounts. We have had GA4 up on the sites since last year's cutover. I'm now trying to clean things up.
Many of our older customers had GAU up for some years, and we're currently initializing the tag manager like:
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-<GAU PROPERTY>" async>
</script>

And we have GA4 tagged:
gtag('config', '<GA4-MEASUREMENTID>');

We now have GA4 properties for all accounts, so ideally I'd like to update that initialization to:
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<GA4-MEASUREMENTID>" async>
</script>

and leaving the gtag in place. Will the change to the initialization result in loss of data?

No, it'll just help the tag initialise more efficiently to the GA4 property
